# Pyspark How to ignore/omit the record which are more than 3

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have got the below data in my source CSV file

```
c1,c2,c3
1,4,46
2,6,246
4,7,542,87
5,7,623
5,7,623,32432
```

Expected Output:

```
c1,c2,c3
1,4,46
2,6,246
5,7,623
```

How to remove/ignore the record if it's more than 3 while reading the file into data frame. is there any particular option in spark.read.csv API.
I've tried maxColumns options, but it just throws the error.

Kindly help me with the appproach if we dont have any options in spark read API.

I thought of this approach

```
spark.read.text().split(',').alias('columncount').filter(" columncount > 3")
```

But It would be nice if we have any inbuild function/ option to do that while reading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should provide the expected output

```
spark.read.schema(schema).option("mode","DROPMALFORMED").csv('/FileStore/tables/altemetric_inter').show()
```